# RegEx: Replaces every match that occurs, but not in the first 8 characters

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have a textfile which contains some service usage data. I want to replace every dot (.) with a comma (,). This needs to be done due to decimal seperator inconsitancy. Then remove all spaces, then separate every column with a semikolon (;).

Original Data:

```
A.FOOBAR       0.000        0.000          0.000          0.000        0.061         0.000        0.000        0.061
AFOOB.BI       0.000        0.000          0.000          0.000        0.085         0.000        0.000        0.085
ABFOOB         0.000        0.000          0.000          0.000        0.000         0.000        0.000        0.000
ABFUUUA        0.000        0.000          0.000          0.000        0.061         0.000        0.000        0.061
ACFOO.GA       0.000        0.000          0.000          0.000        0.061         0.000        0.000        0.061
ADFOO.BA       0.000        0.000          0.000          0.000        0.061         0.000        0.000        0.061
AFOO.ER        0.000        0.000          0.000          0.000        0.061         0.000        0.000        0.061
AFBARFE1       0.000        0.000          0.000          0.000        0.061         0.000        0.000        0.061
AGFOOFD        0.000        0.000          0.000          0.000        0.061         0.000        0.000        0.061
AGFOOO.K       0.000        0.000          0.000          0.000        0.061         0.000        0.000        0.061
```

My current regex looks like:

```
echo in.txt > sed -r 's/[[:blank:]]+/;/g' | sed -r 's/\./,/g'
```

This results in

```
A,FOOBAR;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,061;0,000;0,000;0,061
AFOOB,BI;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,085;0,000;0,000;0,085
ABFOOB;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,000
```

Of cource this matches also the first dot... I cannot use the 2g-Operator because not every username contains a dot. How am I able to "not match" the first 8 characters?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please add the regex engine tag to your Question. See the regex excerpt saying "all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could make use of awk instead of sed, replacing all dots with a comma, except for the first field.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[[:blank:]]+";OFS=";"}{for(x=2;x<=NF;x++) {gsub("\\.",",",$x)}}1' file
```

In parts

```
awk '
BEGIN{                 
  FS="[[:blank:]]+"       # Field separator is 1+ occurrences of spaces or tabs
  OFS=";"                 # Output field separator is a semicolon
}
{
  for(x=2;x<=NF;x++) {    # Loop all fields, start at the second field. NF is the number of all fields
    gsub("\\.",",",$x)    # Replace all dots with a comma
  }
}1                        # 1 evaluates to true, default action to print current line
' file                    # input file
```

Output

```
A.FOOBAR;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,061;0,000;0,000;0,061
AFOOB.BI;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,085;0,000;0,000;0,085
ABFOOB;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,000
ABFUUUA;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,061;0,000;0,000;0,061
ACFOO.GA;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,061;0,000;0,000;0,061
ADFOO.BA;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,061;0,000;0,000;0,061
AFOO.ER;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,061;0,000;0,000;0,061
AFBARFE1;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,061;0,000;0,000;0,061
AGFOOFD;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,061;0,000;0,000;0,061
AGFOOO.K;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,061;0,000;0,000;0,061
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS=";"
}
{
  val=substr($0,9)
  gsub(/\./,",",val)
  $0=substr($0,1,8) val
  $1=$1
}
1
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                      ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                     ##Using BEGIN section of this program.
  OFS=";"                  ##Setting OFS to ; here.
}
{
  val=substr($0,9)         ##Creating val with sub string for current line.
  gsub(/\./,",",val)       ##Globally substituting to substitute dot with , in val.
  $0=substr($0,1,8) val    ##Re-creating current line with sub string of 8 chars and val
  $1=$1                    ##re shuffling $1 here.
}
1                          ##Printing current line here.
' Input_file               ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides 2 working `awk` answer, using `gnu awk`, you can also use this shorter command:

```sh
awk -v OFS=';' '{$1=$1; print substr($0, 1, 8) gensub(/\./, ",", "g", substr($0, 9))}' file

A.FOOBAR;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,061;0,000;0,000;0,061
AFOOB.BI;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,085;0,000;0,000;0,085
ABFOOB;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,000
ABFUUUA;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,061;0,000;0,000;0,061
ACFOO.GA;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,061;0,000;0,000;0,061
ADFOO.BA;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,061;0,000;0,000;0,061
AFOO.ER;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,061;0,000;0,000;0,061
AFBARFE1;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,061;0,000;0,000;0,061
AGFOOFD;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,061;0,000;0,000;0,061
AGFOOO.K;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,000;0,061;0,000;0,000;0,061
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;s/^([^ .]*)\./\1\n/;ta;s/ +/;/g;y/\n./.,/' file
```

Replace every period in the first field by a newline.

Replace one or more spaces by a semi-colons.

Translate newlines back to periods and periods to commas.